# "UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL" Error in Code

Tags: c, cs50

So I am currently taking this cs50 course and I can't seem to figure out what the error/crash mentioned relates to!

I am trying to make my code check if the input from the command line is an integer or not. For example, ./caesar 2 is valid but ./caesar 2z returns ./caesar key.

Error Message:[image]

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

//string error_key = "./caesar key \n";

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        if (isdigit(argv[1]) == 0)
        {
            printf("./caesar key \n");
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            int string_to_int = atoi(argv[1]);
            printf("%i\n",string_to_int);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("./caesar key \n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is undefined behavior:

```
isdigit(argv[1])
```

`argv[1]` is not a character, it's a pointer. As a pointer most likely has a value higher than can be represented in an `unsigned char`, it causes an error with LLVM's Undefined Behavior Sanitizer.

Quoting from POSIX, which is aligned to the ISO C standard:

> The c argument is an int, the value of which the application shall ensure is a character representable as an unsigned char or equal to the value of the macro EOF. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined.